# If $C >0$ and that $X,Y$ are random variables such that $X>Y$, is it always true that $P(X>C) \leq P(Y>C)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $C >0$ and that $X,Y$ are random variables such that $X>Y$. I am wondering if it is true in general, or under what conditions do we have:

$$
P(X>C) \leq P(Y>C)
$$

In other words, if my random variable $X$ is bounded below by $Y$, is the event $\{X>C\}$ a subset of $\{Y>C\}$? Thanks.

Comment: If $X > Y$ almost surely, and $Y > C$ almost surely, then $X > Y > C$ almost surely. The same transitivity property of inequality applies.

Comment: This was asked very recently. Same class, with same homework?

Comment: @Did, This is a stepping stone to a research problem I have been stuck on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (although I think you got the direction of the inequality wrong in your question. If $X>Y$ it is true that $P(X> C) \ge P(Y>C)$).

If $X>Y$ then for any outcome where $Y>C,$ we also have $X>C$ (in other words, as events, $\{Y>C\}\subseteq \{X>C\}$). As a result the event $X>C$ occurs at least as often as $Y>C$ so we must have $P(X>C)\ge P(Y>C)$.